# Selection of Indexes in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, index

I have a table with following 3 fields

```
1) Id      bigint
2) Name    varchar(100)
2) Country varchar(50)
3) State   varchar(50)
4) City    varchar(50)
```

In a country there are no. of states and in a state there are no. of city

I have two queries

a) If I want to know name of persons who are living in a city='Nagpur'

1. should I use index only on column city
2. should I use composite index on city,State & Country
3. should I use composite index on country, state & city

b) If I know that person with ID 1 to 100 are in Nagpur, for such case

1. should I create index on ID field
2. should I create index on City field

If you will suggest to create index on id field that reason will be

1. Due to it is a bigint and bigint occupy only 4 bytes
2. Id field is unique so it has more selectivity, so even if output of both query will be same Index on Id will give faster respnose.

Comment: Normalize your data prior of thinking of indexes

Comment: `bigint` is 8 bytes rather than 4 BTW

Comment: ....And that's 5 fields but you have two `2` fields...

Answer (score 2):

As Oleg mentions, you really should normalize.  For your scenarios, though:

**A** - I would use an index on `City INCLUDE ([name])` - you don't need to sort by `name` as well  but you do want that field at the leaf level of the index.

**B** - I'm not sure what you are asking here.  If you have an auto-incrementing `ID` then that should be your clustered index.

There's a lot of reasons to use an auto-incrementing `ID` as your clustered key.  I won't go in depth on these (there are a ton of resources, and [Kim Tripp](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/) is a really good place to start):

- Will only insert new records at the end of the index
- Narrow (since it will be a part of every other index)
- Unique (keeps it narrow since non-unique indexes need a "uniqueifier" additional int added)
- Non-nullable

Comment: But in this case if id field is not incremental or primary key than what should I do

Comment: Why do you even have an `id` field  then?  If you're not normalizing, and not using it as a PK, then what purpose does it serve?

Comment: It is not like that I not used Id field as primary key in my table. I just want to clear my doubts that if there is any other field as primary field than whom should i use in index